# What is the correct way to layout this sql lite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Failing to pay attention in database class is now catching up with me as I try to design my own project. I'm trying to use databases in Android.

Let's say I have a database with two tables. The first is like this:

```
_id(Primary Key) || Type(Foreign Key) || Cost || Size || Date
```

_id is auto-incrementing, and I never display it.

The next table is like this:

```
Type(Primary Key) || Size
```

The first table is named DATABASE_TABLE, and the second is named DATABASE_EXTENDED.

Now when I add things to my first table, I also add the corresponding values to my second table. When I query my first table, it shows up correctly. When I query the second table, it doesn't show different types of the size option.

Example: If I added:

```
Type || Size
____________
King || Full
King || Half
```

and queried table 2, it would only return

```
 King || Full
```

I've tried designating the size as a foreign key, but it does nothing (and throws errors).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here are the appropriate code snippets:

Code for inserting everything:

```
public long insertRecord(String type, int cost, String size, String date){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues others = new ContentValues();        
    values.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
    values.put(KEY_COST, cost);
    values.put(KEY_SIZE, size);
    values.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    others.put(KEY_TYPE, type);
    others.put(KEY_SIZE, size);
    db.insert(DATABASE_EXTENDED, null, others);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
}
```

Code for querying everything:

```
public Cursor getAllTitles() {

    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{                        
                    KEY_TYPE,
                    KEY_COST,
                    KEY_SIZE,
                    KEY_DATE},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

}
```

And the code for querying the second table:

```
public Cursor getAllTypes(){
    return db.query(DATABASE_EXTENDED, new String[]{
            KEY_TYPE,
            KEY_SIZE},
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null);
}
```

For last minute clarification, here is a sample:

```
type        cost    size        date_installed
King        478     full        2/14/2015
Queen       478     half        2/14/2015
King        478     half        2/14/2015
```

and if I queried the second table, it would return:

```
type    size
King    full
Queen   half
```

Answer (score 0):

Per usual, I figure out my answer as soon as I take the time posting.

I made a composite key for table 2.

So, now it's:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 =
        "create table type_category (type text not null, " +
                                    "size text not null, " +
                                    "primary key (size, type));";
```

vs

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE1 =
        "create table type_category (type text primary key not null, " +
                                    "size text not null);";
```

I am still getting errors about the keys not being unique, but I think I can work those out with some simple queries and error checking.